# Could work an app then reboot iPhone?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, state-restoration

I have an iOS Objective-C application, and this implements a store restoration function.
But if I reboot my iPhone while my app is running... they continue working before reboot?

I'm trying reboot my iPhone and apps in the background continue running in the background, but when I bring some to foreground, they show the launch screen like I would open them for the first time.
How to make sure that the application state is called before rebooting?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [State restoration only works when connected to Xcode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34586124/state-restoration-only-works-when-connected-to-xcode)

Comment: Make sure you search for the question before asking a new: https://www.google.se/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=ios+app+preserve+state+termination+stackoverflow&*

Comment: I see, you should make the question more clear. https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/TheAppLifeCycle/TheAppLifeCycle.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH2-SW3, on reboot , the app state will be **Not Running**,that means, iOS will terminate your app. Furthermore if you read the documentation we can see that - "If an app is currently running in the background and not suspended, the system calls the applicationWillTerminate: of its app delegate prior to termination. The system does not call this method when the device reboots"

Answer (score 0):

iOS has asystem call which is called `applicationWillTerminate` and this method doesn't get called when you reboot your device. When a reboot occurs, all apps, which work in the background, save their state and start again with this state when the reboot finishes.

Comment: But Sneak comment that when I reboot the iPhone, "the app state will be Not Running,that means, iOS will terminate your app" So the app in background not save the background state because applicationWillTerminate isn't called and the state then reboot is not running, true??